# How to organize a java project, esp. where to put the libs?

Tags: java

Can someone please enlighten me how to organize files in my Project?

I work with the command line. I don't want to bother with IDE Tools for now. My tiny program consists of just one .java file, but uses a bunch of 20 libs or so.

This is what I did. In the first line of my .java I wrote package `com.mycompany.app.module;` The .java and later the .class file are located in

```
/home/sweethome/Projects/Proj1/com/mycompany/app/module
```

Next I wanted to create a jar to put package that would include

```
com/mycompany/app/module/LogonToken.class
```

Is this ok so far? Here comes my real question: where do I put the 20 libs this class needs to run?

```
com/mycompany/app/module/libs
```

Comment: Does your application only need those 20 libraries to run, or does it also need them when compiling?

Comment: Sorry, both compile and run

Comment: I think the concept you're missing is that of the `classpath`. That is pretty fundamental material covered on all resources worth your time - including the Oracle Java tutorial.

Comment: I know how to compile and run but was interested in a state of the art organization of a project. Found this resource now, answered all my questions: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Fairly standard java project consists of three top level folders:

/bin - empty folder that will contain compiled .class files

/lib - contains third party .jar files

/src - contains .java source files

Answer (score 1):

The clean way to handle external dependencies is to use a build system like Maven, and declare them in a pom.xml file. This does not require an IDE.

At the very first moment, this seems to require some extra effort, but will actually amortise very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Does your question is build jar file with 20 libs and class? If it's true, here is answer of your question

[Creating a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: I sounds like the .jar they describe has no structure in it. Since I have a package, don't I need the above mentioned dir structure com/mycompany/app/module/ inside the .jar

Comment: No, it has structure in it. You can build .jar file with your structure. Same you build .jar file with IDE, this jar file include your structure inside. Ex: `jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class`